# How can I add dependency to the current class using AngularJs and TypeScript?

Tags: angularjs, typescript, dependency-injection

Let's say I have a component class as follows;

```
@Component({
  selector: "my",
  templateUrl: "/app/my.html"
})
export class MyComponent extends MyBase {
  helper: Helper;
  constructor() 
  { 
     helper = new Helper(this);
  } 
}
```

The Helper class lives in another file like this.

```
export class Helper {
    constructor(protected component: MyBase)
    {

    }
}
```

It looks like I can't use dependency injection for my helper class no matter what since it is storing a reference to the component. The only way I see to make this work is by leaving it the way it is or by setting the component instance after injection as follows which I don't like either.

```
export class MyComponent extends MyBase {
  constructor(public helper:Helper) 
  { 
    helper.component = this;
  } 
}
```

The Helper class lives in another file like this.

```
@Injectable()
export class Helper {
    public component : MyBase;
}
```

Both of these feel wrong but I don't see a reasonable alternative.

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe the best way in this scenarios is to eliminate the dependent class instance.

The real implementation of the helper class actually looks like this:

```
export abstract class MvcAction<TComponent>
{
  constructor(protected component:TComponent)
  public abstract complete(): void;
}
```

The subclass looks like the this:

```
export class CustomAction extends MvcAction<TComponent>
{
  constructor(protected component:TComponent)
  {
      super(component);
  }
  public abstract complete(): void;
}
```

And the base component class calls the method as needed:

```
public perform(action: MvcAction<T>) {
    action.complete();
}
```

So, it now seems more practical to call action passing in the instance which will eliminate the contructor dependency with the new implementation looking as follows.

```
export abstract class MvcAction<ComponentBase>
{
  public abstract complete(component: ComponentBase): void;
}
```

The subclass now looks like the this:

```
export class CustomAction extends MvcAction<TComponent>
{
  public complete(component: TComponent): void
  {
      // Do something with the component.
  }
}
```

And the component base class calls the method as needed.

```
public perform(action: MvcAction<ComponentBase>) {
    action.complete(this);
}
```

My component now works fine with dependency injection without the unneeded instance dependency as follows:

```
export class SomeComponent extends ComponentBase<any> {
  constructor(protected customAction: CustomAction ) {
  }
}
```

And template code is like this:

```
<a (click)="perform(customAction)">Do Custom Action</a>
```